# Python tkinter label orientation

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Is there any way to make the tkinter `label widget` vertical? Something like this

[image: sample label]

or is it just simply impossible? I have already look around and can't seems to find how to do it.By the way, i have tried `orient='vertical'` but `label widget` doesn't seems to support it.

Comment: Just use an image with the rotated text.

With Tk-8.6, you could create a text on a rotated canvas element, but getting Tk-8.6 to work with python requieres some work.

Comment: @DominicKexel can't do that.. my label texts are dynamic. but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well, I don't know of any way to do it like that, but would `"\n".join(text)` be anything useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to display rotated text in the tkinter Label widget.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve vertical display, without the text rotation, by using the wraplength option which set to 1 will force the next char into a new line:

```
 Label( master_frame,  text="Vertical Label", wraplength=1 ).grid( row=0, column=0 )
```

Comment: This seems to ignore `" "`. Replace `"Vertical Label".replace(" ", " \n")`.

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue I have also run into, and unfortunately there still is no simple angle argument for the `tkinter Label` widget. Nevertheless, to work around this whilst allowing dynamic labels, you can use the `create_text()` function within the `tkinter canvas`, which does have an angle argument. An example snippet from my code:

```
canvas_1_manage = tkinter.Canvas(nodeManager.window, width = 12, height = 50)
canvas_1_manage.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
canvas_1_manage.create_text(6, 50, text = "Node", angle = 90, anchor = "w")
```

This is part of a window builder function which produces the following:
[nodeManager Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBCDC.png)